# Ghost CMS and SEO

Tags: javascript, seo, ghost

i'm looking for someone using Ghost CMS for his blog because i have some questions.

I'm updating my blog website, and i did a search work to find the better cms , other than WP (WP i hate you !)

I found Ghost which is very light, usefull , and worked with **NodeJS**.

But here is my question : Considering that **contents will be load from javascript** and no php, what about SEO with *Google* ?

I've already tried to search on France's forum, but no result.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's SEO question, not programming related.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what programming language you run on the server.

The client makes an HTTP request and gets some content. That content might come from a static file, JavaScript, PHP, Perl, C#, COBOL or anything else.

There is no way for the client to tell the difference and no reason for it to care.

Comment: So using PHP, nodeJS or Angular technology will no impact on my SEO ?

Comment: Angular is a browser-side technology and could cause problems. Node and PHP are not.

Answer (score 1):

Ghost has SEO built in and that should not bother you. You can even add custom code in the header and footer instantly.

Adding HTTPS to your ghost blog is also key to improving SEO. You can check out this [post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04) on how to secure nginx with letsencrpyt.

Answer (score 0):

Ghost does use javascript, but it does so on the server (node.js). I believe you are getting confused about the difference between client and server side javascript. It is true that it is a big challenge to get good SEO from client side script (AngularJS), but since Ghost is running on the server, it will not have any impact on your SEO.

Now, to answer your question:

Ghost has very good SEO. It includes useful meta tags and does a good job of caching your pages for faster access.

You will have to make sure you enter in the correct descriptions for your blog.

Ghost also has great SEO tools for each individual entry. It allows you to set the title and description that will be seen by the search engine robots as well as tag each entry for better interlinking among similar topics.

I converted from using WordPress a few weeks ago and my site now loads in under 1.5 seconds. My WordPress site loads in 3.95 seconds.

Ghost has [excellent directions](http://support.ghost.org/import-posts-wordpress-ghost/) for migrating all of your content from WordPress to Ghost, but make sure you follow the instructions carefully. Unfortunately, to move your images you cannot have your site hosted on WordPress.com, it must be self hosted (it requires a plugin from [Cloudinary.com](http://cloudinary.com) and one for [Ghost](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ghost/)).

I was able to get all 115 of my posts from the past many years and all of the related images migrated over in a matter of about 30 minutes.

It is well worth it. Make sure you read the [WordPress vs Ghost comparison guide](https://ghost.org/vs/wordpress/) before making the plunge as there are some major differences between the two.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You already picked up right CMS. Ghost has built in SEO options. You can add custom meta data for google search engine, facebook open graph  meta data, twitter card meta data etc in ghost.

There have option to add meta information in every post.

Here following the screenshot of that,

[image]

[image]

You may check the source code of the following ghost blog,

view-source:https://darkbiz.themeix.com/

there have the proper meta data for search engine, facebook and twitter which is really great for SEO.

[image]

Best of luck with ghost.